# PHP using $_GET to change a include file in div when link is clicked in MVC model

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am learning php to develop a web application. I am trying to use the MVC model and use `$_GET` to fetch user input on URL as controller and method through `.htaccess` file setup. However, I found the normal `$_GET` function is not working anymore when I am trying to update a div through clicking a link.

It would work without `.htaccess` file like the following example:

```
<a href="?grade=grade1">Grade 1</a>

<?php $grade=$_GET['grade'];?>

<div> <?php include ($grade.'.php');?> </div>
```

I tried JQuery, but it doesn't work in my i.e somehow. I also tried button action. It worked, but I still think link looks better. Is there anyway to use `_GET` in above example in MVC model? Any other suggestions to work around it? I am new to web development, I want a simple solution. :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

You would need to post your .htaccess file to see the rewrite rules that you are using however the example code you posted will work. I will warn against using it however due to something known as a file inclusion vulnerability which means someone can enter a different file in that GET variable and it will be displayed to the user.

Here is a link that provides a general overview of MVC and how to use it properly.

https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

(I wanted to add this as a comment, unfortunately I don't have the required reputation.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! If I use button action to change the include file name. Would that resolve the issue, since URL will not include the file name? Or is there better way to include a file, and keep it safe?

Comment: It's best to never use user supplied input to include a file. You could have something like $_GET['grade'] = 1-5 or something similar and use a switch() to determine what those numbers correspond to.